# How to navigate within the app without loosing global state?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm using `react-router` to navigate within my app. But this causes to reload the whole page when I route to a new path (=URL). This means the app looses it's global state (managed by `react-redux`).

So, my question is: how can I navigate within the app without loosing it's global state?

Comment: Can you provide the example of your code? I would say you're pushing new routes incorrectly. Because react-router only mimicks navigation in SPA and it should not reload your page

Comment: It would also be better to include your `react-router` setup as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use NavLink instead of a  link tag, NavLink lets you navigate without refreshing the page, otherwise, the global state always gets lost when your refresh the app, Another solution you can use localStorage to persist data, and when you go back to the app you add your data to your store from localStorage.

Comment: Thank you, seems to work (I have to check possible side effect later)!